# Inspect template strings before concatenation

Tags: node.js, template-literals

I am generating error messages like so:

```
throw `Do not recognize eventType '${eventType}', recognized events are ${recognizedEvents}.`;
```

---

the problem is recognizedEvents is an object, but it will simply be toString'ed...Anyway, so I could do this:

```
throw `Do not recognize eventType '${eventType}', recognized events are ${util.inspect(recognizedEvents)}.`;
```

---

the problem is not only that it's more verbose - sometimes I simply forget to call util.inspect(). Even TypeScript let's me compile template literals if an object is passed directly. What is a good technique here to make sure objects get inspected to a reasonable depth in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Would you be more likely to remember to use a [tagged template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates) instead of `util.inspect` within each template string?

```
function err(strings, eventType, recognizedEvents) {

  return `${strings[0]}${eventType}${strings[1]}${util.inspect(recognizedEvents)}`;
}

throw err`Do not recognize eventType '${eventType}', recognized events are ${recognizedEvents}.`;
```

Combined with @JackBashford's suggestion of using `JSON.stringify` instead of `util.inspect`, you can get the object stringified as deep as it can be.

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman the documentation explains it better than I ever could, but by prefixing the template string with that function, all of the plain strings are pushed into the `strings` array, and any expressions are additional arguments to the tag function.